# How to override Aurelia ViewModel resolution?

Tags: typescript, single-page-application, aurelia

The [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) framework has a strong appeal to convention-over-configuration.

In its docs [sample app (typescript)](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.8/doc/article/getting-started/1), we've got a source code structure like this:

```
.
├── index.html
├── config.js
├── src
    ├── main.ts
    ├── app.ts         // viewmodel
    ├── app.html       // view
    ├── welcome.ts     // viewmodel
    ├── welcome.html   // view
    ├── users.ts       // viewmodel
    ├── users.html     // view
    (...)
```

For organization purposes, I would rather organize the sources with each view/viewmodel/private components/etc in their own folder, obtaining a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── index.html
├── config.js
├── src
    ├── main.ts
    ├── app
        ├── app.ts            // viewmodel
        ├── app.html          // view
    ├── welcome
        ├── welcome.ts        // viewmodel
        ├── welcome.html      // view
    ├── users
        ├── users.ts          // viewmodel
        ├── user-info.ts      // view-specific component (1)
        ├── user-detail.ts    // view-specific component (2)
        ├── users.html        // view
    (...)
```

Is there a way to do this implementing a custom resolver or overriding the convention? That is, I want to avoid explicit path boilerplate code in my [Router](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.8/doc/article/getting-started/4) config. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a workaround.

I see that you don't want to type the specific path all the time, like: `welcome/welcome`. So, you can put the routes array in a variable, and then replace all moduleIds, according to your pattern. Like this:

```
let routes = [
    { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome', moduleId: 'welcome', nav: true, title: 'Welcome' },
    { route: 'test', name: 'test', moduleId: 'test', nav: true, title: 'Test' },
 ];

updateRoutes(routes);

config.map(routes);
```

Update routes function:

```
 function updateRoutes(routes) {
     for (i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        let route = routes[i];
        if (route.moduleId.indexOf('/') === -1) {
            route.moduleId = `${route.moduleId}/${route.moduleId}`;
            routes[i] = route;
        }
     }
 }
```

So, `welcome` becomes `welcome/welcome`. Be aware that the function will only replace the moduleId if there's no '/' in its value;

Using this way, you aren't "hurting" the framework, as explained in the @JeremyDanyow's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Simple but do the work. Marking as accepted because it addresses the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

In `main.js`, `.setRoot()` becomes `.setRoot('app/app')`.  This is required because `setRoot` with no args assumes an `app.js` at the root of your project.

Route configuration changes are limited to the `moduleId`... This:

```js
config.map([
  { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome',      moduleId: 'welcome',      nav: true, title: 'Welcome' },
  { route: 'users',         name: 'users',        moduleId: 'users',        nav: true, title: 'Github Users' },
]);
```

Becomes this:

```js
config.map([
  { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome',      moduleId: 'welcome/welcome',    nav: true, title: 'Welcome' },
  { route: 'users',         name: 'users',        moduleId: 'users/users',        nav: true, title: 'Github Users' },
]);
```

Not sure if this answers your question.  Are you looking for a way for the router to convert the moduleId from `'welcome'` to `'welcome/welcome'`?

Comment: I believe he is looking for a way to rewrite the convention. Like the `ViewLocator.prototype.convertOriginToViewUrl`, but for view and view-models, not only views

Comment: In that case, the moduleId would be `moduleId: 'welcome'` and the locator would look for `welcome/welcome`

Comment: Jeremy and @Fabio - spot on! 'welcome' id should look for 'welcome/welcome'. The thing here is more about understanding the framework under-the-hoods and find out what level of flexibility is possible to achieve in a convention manner.

Comment: ok- I'll see if there's a way.  Word of warning to you- this could become very confusing if you are to start using partial module ids in route configuration while using normal module ids in `import {Foo} from 'my/module/id'` statements. I would recommend against doing this, even if there's a way.

Comment: @Jeremy: Right. My concern (and curiosity) began when I was wondering about big projects: Lob applications with 30+ views, some of them with non-shared particular components. How should we organize the project in this case? All-in-one folder seems a little messy for me...

Comment: I think a lot of people are using the same approach you're proposing (myself included):  putting related functionality in folders.  I would stop short of aliasing module ids.  Here's an example app I put together a while back that uses the folder approach:  https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze-northwind

Comment: Thank you for all the considerations. At last you convinced me: I'll stick with the built-in defaults.